# I can't find chromium on Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 13.10

It should be there right?

Ubuntu 13.10 - 64Bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be available in the Ubuntu Software Center, yes. If you search for:

```
Chromium
```

you should have results including the Chromium Web Browser and Chromium BSU, an arcade game.

You should also be able to install by clicking on this button:

[image: Install via the software center]

If Chromium Web Browser isn't showing up in the Software Center results, it may be because 13.10 is still in beta.